# What is the correct code to avoid resetting the target in EXTENDED_TRACKING mode

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, timeline

I use model target to show a 3d increase. Until everything is ok
I use Timeline / Playable Director to follow a timeline each time the target is detected.
My issue is the following:
Because I use the tracker device extended mode, the target is retriggered when the tracker mode switches to extended tracker mode, and therefore I would like the target to be triggered only when the tracking is lost but not when the target goes into extended mode tracker.I if I remove the Timeline then it becomes normal, that is to say that the extended tracking mode works coorectively.
Someone to help me?
Thank you

```
protected override void OnTrackingFound()
{
    base.OnTrackingFound();

    // Play Timeline when target is found
    GetComponent<PlayableDirector>().Play();

}

protected override void OnTrackingLost()
{
    base.OnTrackingLost();

    // Stop Timeline when target is lost
    GetComponent<PlayableDirector>().Stop();
}
```

Comment: Don't understand your question .. there is no extended tracking involved in the snipped you posted ...

Comment: @derHugo  because the extended tracking mode is already selected in vuforia configuration
Do I need to respect it in the code ???

Comment: Well I can only guess that your script is based on the `DefaultTrackable` or how it is called .. you should probably edit it and say that an extended tracking doesn't trigger a tracking found nor tracking lost .. but this is hard to tell without seeing the actual code you use

Comment: Well done, that's exactly it: I use DefaultTrackableEventHandler
But I don't know which is the best code, would you have any suggestion pls ???

Answer (score 0):

I guess your script is based on the `DefaultTrackableEventHandler` which does

```c#
/// <summary>
/// Implementation of the ITrackableEventHandler function called when the
/// tracking state changes.
/// </summary>
public void OnTrackableStateChanged(TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus, TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
{
    if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
        newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED ||
        newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
    {
        OnTrackingFound();
    }
    else
    {
        OnTrackingLost();
    }
}
```

As you can see the `OnTrackingFound` is also called when the tracking changes between `DETECTED`, `TRACKED` and `EXTENDED_TRACKED`.

---

As far as I know without having to change too much you could simply check whether the `PlayableDirector` is already playing or not

```c#
// Better reference this already via the Inspector
[SerializeField] private PlayableDirector director;

private void Awake()
{
    if(!director) director = GetComponent<PlayableDirector>();
} 

protected override void OnTrackingFound()
{
    base.OnTrackingFound();

    // Play Timeline when target is found
    if(director.state != PlayableState.Playing) director.Play();   
}

protected override void OnTrackingLost()
{
    base.OnTrackingLost();

    // Stop Timeline when target is lost
   director.Stop();
}
```

---

Alternatively you can ofcourse implement your own version of the handler and simply not call the methods again if the state is basically the same:

```c#
public class MyTrackableEventHandler : MonoBehaviour, ITrackableEventHandler
{
    [SerializeField] private TrackableBehaviour _trackableBehaviour;
    [SerializeField] private PlayableDirector director;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!_trackableBehaviour) _trackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();
        _trackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);

        if(!director) director = GetComponent<PlayableDirector>();
    }

    public void OnTrackableStateChanged(TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus, TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
    {
        if(previousStatus == newStatus) return;

        var newTracked = newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED 
                || newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED 
                || newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED;

        var previousTracked = previousStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED 
                || previousStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED 
                || previousStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED;

        if(newTracked && previousTracked) return;

        if (newTracked)
        {
            OnTrackingFound();
        }
        else
        {
            OnTrackingLost();
        }
    }

    private void OnTrackingFound()
    {
        director.Play();
    }

    private void OnTrackingLost()
    {
        director.Stop();
    }
}
```

---

*Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: Thanks for your help
But I tried with the 2 proposals but it does not work
The problem remains the same